# how to pass a socket instance over UDS

Tags: python, sockets, ipc

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket

worker=Pool(processes=1)
worker.apply_async(Processor,())
server =socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind('sock.s')
server.listen(1)
connection,addr=server.accept()

sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('IP' , PORT))


connection.sendall(sock)
```

Hi
I have written a python script with `multiprocessing` module which creates some processes. i need to transfer data over these processes. so i've used `unix domain socket` for IPC. now i need to send a socket instance from the parent process to the childs (`sock` instance in above code, the `Processor` function connects to server as soon as is created). 
is there any way to do this? what is `sendMsg` and `recvMsg` in this regard?

Comment: where is the code in which you send the socket? your provided example sends `ID` and not a socket...

Comment: i edited the code right now

Comment: still not sending anything to apply_async @amir

Comment: i don't want to send anything by `apply_async`. i want to send that `sock` instance with `UDS` socket

Comment: do you want that because you want to send the socket at any time to the process? because if that's the case `multiprocessing.Pool` isn't really what you want to use

Comment: yes, exactly. i want to send the socket to the process at any time. what should i do?